# recover mysql from dump by adding prefixes to database names

Tags: mysql, database-restore

Is there a way to restore mysql database from a dump file which was made by mysqldump command with --all-databases option, and add automatically to all restored databases the prefix

old_ like

- old_db1
- old_db2

and so on ... Or is there any option to skip existing databases?

Comment: assuming `create table ...` doesn't ever appear in your actual data, you could use a quick sed/awk rewrite to do `/create table/create table old_/`.

Comment: I am not so advanced user in linux ... :(

Comment: and I am speaking not about tables, but the databases names.

Comment: same thing applies - the dumps will have `create database` as well.

Comment: are you sure I will not have server crashed on 7GB dump file?

Comment: why should it? if it can suck up the 7gig dump without trouble, it's going to suck up 7gig + a few extra characters for your db/table name prefixes.

Comment: did I understood right? I should search and replace via awk in the file the statements and then  restore it. Right?

Comment: yes. basically `cat dump.sql | awk ... | mysql`